# Progressive web apps: Update sw.js on Single Page Applications

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

So we're building a progressive web app and of course we are using service workers which are awesome.

Whenever we release a new version of our app, we update the version number in our sw.js file. At page load, the browser detects that sw.js has changed and fires the "install" and "activate" events, which in turn cache the right resources for offline use.

This works great. But from my understanding, it will only be fired **at page load**. So If a user adds the app to their home screen and always uses this shortcut to access the app, the "refresh" event won't be fired very often, and so these users won't see updates as often as they would with a non SPA web app.

So my question is how would you go about updating a Single Page Progressive Web App that uses sw.js as an update process?

I have thought of several solutions that included a timeout that would query the server in search of a new version and compare it to the local etc. But this just seems a bit odd..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Checking for a new version of `sw.js` happens upon [every navigation request](https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/blob/master/explainer.md#updating-a-service-worker) to a page under the service worker's scope. So you're correct that if a SPA stays open indefinitely, and no "real" navigations occur, there won't be any checks for `sw.js` updates.

This is mitigated somewhat by the fact that most browsers will eventually unload background pages from memory and then reload them if/when you bring them back to the foreground. But that's not a deterministic thing you could count on.

You can use the [`ServiceWorkerRegistration.update()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/update) method to force the browser to check for updates to `sw.js`, the same way it would if there had been a navigation.

It's up to you to determine how often you would like to call that method. If you wanted to match the behavior you get with "real" navigations, you could do something like the following:

```
function spaNavigate(url) {
  // Do what you'd normally do to update page content,
  // use the History API to change the location to `url`, etc.

  // Then, force a service worker update check:
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(registration) {
      registration.update();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks so much fo contributing to this great feature : )